# How Can I Export a Factory and/or its Method in MEF 2?

Tags: c#, .net, mef, object-composition, mef2

I am looking into [MEF 2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.composition) (Microsoft.Composition) and am looking to integrate it with my existing code base.

My current codebase has an `IFactory` interface with a simple signature:

```
public interface IFactory<T>
{
    T Create();
}
```

I would like to register my factories so that if I do an export on a factory, it is registered as a `Func<T>` for the factory's `T` output.  So something like this:

```
[Export]
public class Factory : IFactory<Class>
{
    public Class Create() => new Class();
}
```

Will return a new `Class` instance and a reference to the `Create` method (as a `Func<Class>` delegate) with the following code:

```
using ( var container = new ContainerConfiguration()
    // ... magic missing here.
    .CreateContainer() )
{
    var instance = container.GetExport<Class>(); // instance is created from the Factory.Create above.
    var factory = container.GetExport<Func<Class>>(); // this is a reference to the Factory.Create delegate defined above.
}
```

I did see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361081/composing-mef-parts-in-c-sharp-like-a-simple-funq-container), but it doesn't seem to apply for MEF 2.  All sorts of things are different now, but seems much more lightweight/streamlined (as advertised!).

Is it possible to achieve what I am looking to do with MEF 2?

Answer (score 2):

`public Class Create() => new Class();` is not a delegate. In C# 6 this is known as an [Expression-bodied member function](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#expression-bodied-function-members).

The following 2 statements are equivalent in C# 6:

```
// Expression-bodied member function
public MyClass Create() => new MyClass();

// standard member function
public MyClass Create()
{
    return new MyClass();
}
```

As far as resolving `IFactory<Class>` and then using the factory, simply decorate your factory with the type to export and use as needed:

```
[Export( typeof( IFactory<MyClass> ) )]
public class Factory : IFactory<MyClass>
{
    public MyClass Create() => new MyClass();
}
```

After the container has been built up, the resolution is simply:

```
var factory = container.GetExport<IFactory<MyClass>>();

MyClass mc = factory.Create();
```

Comment: Hi @Metro-Smurf thank you for your answer. I do realize that the method is what you describe and not a delegate. I am wanting to make a delegate out of this method, as such: `Func<Class> @delegate = new Func<Class>( factory.Create );` and then register __that__ as the export. Make sense? I also realize that your answer will get me a direct export of an `IFactory<Class>`. However, that is not what I am looking for.  Please refer to my question to see the exact exports that I desire. See: magic. :) If I request a `Class` object, I am actually calling the `factory.Create` somewhere. Thanks again!

Comment: I probably mis-understood the question; sorry about that. I can take a closer look later today, but a couple of things to consider: 1. Use a property export which will simply export whatever is being returned from a property. 2. Give this a read: [Resolving closed types with MEF by Mark Seemann](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/14/ResolvingclosedtypeswithMEF/) Again, apologies for mis-understanding.

Comment: No worries!  We've all been there. :)  I am indeed aware of Mr. Seemann's post, but was looking for another route here if possible. Something that doesn't require me to specify types.  I simply want to `[Export]` an `IFactory` and MEF "just knows" how to call its `Create` method and return the instance.  In Unity there is an `InjectionFactory` that can be used when registering a type.  I am looking for something comparable for MEF 2.  After digging, I did [find this](https://github.com/MefContrib/MefContrib/blob/master/src/MefContrib/Hosting/FactoryExportProvider.cs) but it is MEF 1.